# Getting started with MapReduce/Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Lately, i have reading a lot about MapReduce/Hadoop and think  this is where industry is currently moving to. 
I want to start learning MapReduce/Hadoop and i thought the best way to start would be to implement some small project. However, i tried to do some googling, but couldnt find anything.

Can you guys give me some links or may be some books that can give me a practical introduction to this technology. May be a small project that i can implement on my own to get a better understanding of the technology.

Thanks,
Chander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common examples that get thrown around are creating an inverted index, and implementing grep.

If you're looking for more information:

A really friendly introduction can be found [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXCIItzkn3E)
The original paper is [here.](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html)

And what looks like some good example code to get you going is [here.](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/)

Comment: Sorry but the link is broken for some reason. Can you fix it?

Comment: Working link to original MapReduce paper: http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html

Answer (score 5):

Cloudera (releases a Hadoop distribution) has some fantastic online training videos as well as a virtual machine with everything setup and able to run through examples from the online free training http://www.cloudera.com/resources/?type=Training

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoopresources.html) are some nice articles/videos/tutorials on getting started with MapReduce.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to parachute over Hadoop without understanding MapReduce can be painful. I think the easiest way to understand the hammer is to see a nail. :) I wrote a blog article ([Intro to Parallel Processing with MapReduce](http://mentablog.soliveirajr.com/2012/12/intro-to-parallel-processing-with-mapreduce/)) where I describe a common problem and show how to solve it *with and without MapReduce*. Then I go on to show how MapReduce makes it straightforward to distribute the work on a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest some alternative learning approach like videos and lectures.
Like on YouTube : (You can follow from this one to some more)

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9xnYBVqLws

Answer (score 0):

Hi I thinks this is the best way to start, for free

http://bigdatauniversity.com/bdu-wp/bdu-course/hadoop-fundamentals-i-version-2/